# Problemas para mostrar elementos en laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy realizando esta consulta

```
$ventas = VentasProductos::select('id_factura','=' ,$id);
```

a una tabla de base datos desde un Controller FacturaController y cuando reviso la cantidad de elementos me devuelve que existen elementos pero a la hora de mostrarlos en una vista no me devuelve valores. ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Estimado , este post esta muy pobre le falta edición, ademas la consulta que haces no esta bien ,

Comment: si me pudiera ayudar con la consulta se lo agradeceria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta para usar un Eloquent sería:

```
$ventas = VentasProductos::where('id_factura',$id)->get();
```

Eso sería una consulta al modelo que hiciste. No es `select` ya que eso se usa para especificar campos del modelo que creaste.

Ahora tiene que tener el modelo importado en el Controller que creaste para que funcione también. Pero si ese no es el caso puedes usar `DB` de `Query Builder` que no lo recomiendo pero se usa para consultas que no usan modelos creados en tu proyecto.

```
$ventas = DB::select('select * from nombreTabla where id_factura =:id', ['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias en breve acepto su respuesta. saludos cordiales

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta esta bien pero esta incompleta, es decir una vez que ejecutas dichas operaciones le tienes que indicar con otro método que te devuelva los resultados, en este caso como estás haciendo una consulta con un filtro al final debe tener acceso al métod get();

entonces debería quedar:

```
$ventas = VentasProductos::where('id_factura','=' ,$id)->get();
```